# Dojo uploader issue on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, dojo

I am seeing an issue with the dojox.form.Uploader on Chrome whereby the onComlete function is called prematurely and the function parameter is set as an object of unknown origin {message: "id"} rather than an object representing the server response {result: "success", msg: "Success.", status: 201}.

The problem only occurs on the first request for a page and after that it works fine until the page is reloaded again.

This code used to work until a recent Chrome update (not sure which one). The current version is 65.0.3325.181

The upload is controlled by a button but the actual uploader code is:

```
new dojox.form.Uploader({
  label: "Browse",
  url: '/upload',
  force: 'iframe',
  style: 'width: 300px',
  uploadOnSelect: false,
  onComplete: function (res) {
    console.log(res);
  },
  onError: function (err) {
    console.log("Error")
  },
}
```

On the first upload (after page reload) I see in the console: {message: "id"}.

Subsequent uploads have the expected result: {result: "success", msg: "Success.", status: 201}.

Comment: On further investigation the reference to {message: "id"} is specific to my environment and is probably not useful. The actual problem here seems to be related to the fact that the dojo iframe _fireNextRequest call is taking place before the iframe._frame is loaded. If i add a timeout around that call like: setTimeout(function() {iframe._fireNextRequest();}, 1); then it works.